# How can I update listview when viewmodel values change?

Tags: listview, timer, nativescript, countdown

I'm new to NS and need some help getting something, which should be simple, working.

The app I am toying with is just a simple timing system: When the app starts up, and the refresh button on the UI is tapped, it downloads (using fetch) from the API, a list of alarms (which is simply an array of 'seconds' from which to count down).

Once I have the list downloaded, I'm assigning a variable in the view model to the data I just received. I have a listview which is bound to this variable.

Every second I decrease all the values in the viewmodel by 1, using a timer.

My problem is that the listview doesn't seem to update automatically with the changes I make to it's datasource, which the timer handles every second.

I assumed that if I bound the listview to a value in the viewmodel (array of alarms/seconds), the view would change whenever I updated any of it's bound elements (in this case, when the timer decreases the value of each alarm).

This isn't the case; after initially populating the list view, it's just static, yet the timer is certainly working.

```
const ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

const observableModule = require("data/observable");

const dialogsModule = require("ui/dialogs");

function AlarmsViewModel() {

    const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({

        alarms: [],

        intervalId: null,

        refreshData() {

            this.alarms = [];

            if (this.intervalId) {

                clearInterval(this.intervalId);

            }

            fetch(`http://localhost:3000/alarms`).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {

                const alarms = res.alarms;

                this.alarms = new ObservableArray(alarms);

                this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {

                    this.alarms.forEach((alarm) => {

                        alarm--;

                    });

                }, 1000);

            }).catch(() => {

                dialogsModule.alert({

                    title: "Oops!",

                    message: "An error occured connecting to the API.",

                    okButtonText: "Got it!"

                });

            });

        }

    });

    return viewModel;
}

module.exports = AlarmsViewModel;
```

alarms.xml

```
    <ActionBar title="Alarms" class="action-bar">

    </ActionBar>

    <StackLayout>

        <Button text="Refresh" tap="{{ refreshData }}" />

        <ListView items="{{ alarms }}">

            <ListView.itemTemplate>

                    <Label text="{{ $value }}" class="ends-in"/>

            </ListView.itemTemplate>

        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

</Page>
```

That, every second, the listview elements change according to changes made in it's underlying datasource.

Comment: You could use Observable inside Observable array. So whenever you make a change to a value it updates the Label.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you have to take care if you want to bind your array changes in ListView,

1. You were flipping `alarms` variable between `Array` and `ObservableArray`. You must keep it as an `ObservableArray` always so changes on any index can be captured.
2. You have to use `splice` if you want to replace a value in particular index of an `ObservableArray`.

Here is a [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=TRHFBQ)

Comment: This is great. I didn't realise that I have to keep it that way. I tried to add another field to the array (in reality, the API gives a list of alarms and each alarm has a name and a value) but it wouldn't work. I guess I wasn't entirely accurate with the dataset. Each alarm also has a name so the alarms array would be something like const alarms = [{name: 'Test 1', value:10}, {name: 'Test 2', value:100}]. I'm doing something wrong because when I update your code to target the value key of an alarm, it breaks. I assume I have to declare the value field to be observable?

Comment: Actually, I updated the Playground code with more of what I would like to accomplish.